# Solr, Ignore wildcard query for certain field

Tags: solr

I'd like to query a certain 2 fields in solr. Let's say I have **"description"** and **"keywords"**. Now I want to search for `"dogs" or "cats"` by doing this:

```
q=dog* OR cat*
```

I'm also passing the fields to be searched:

```
qf=description^1 keywords^1
```

So far so good. Now I want to have **"description"** to ignore the wildcards so the search is being more performant. Is there any way to do this in the fieldTypes or in the query itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, well, not exactly that, but you can get the same functionality while at the same time gaining performance:

1. use different analysis for description and keywords. In keywords, use a [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory). This can give you the same functionality as the *, but with much better perf (at the expense of a bigger index, but it is worth it!).
2. in description, just don't use the ngram filter, and partial matches will not be found.